# Using dt.select to populate dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to populate a dropdown with selectedvalues from my database. The reason why I'm using a dt.select is because I don't want to keep calling the stored procedure for every dropdown (I have about 20 dropdowns).

The problem is if there is a value London in Location dropdown and London in Department dropdown, it'll populate in both dropdown. I only want it to populate in Location or in Department. I have a feeling that it could be this part in my code that populating both ddl.

```
if (ddlLocation.Items[j].Value.ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString())
```

I would like to go through the data row and only populate those values.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = obj.runSPHere(GUID);
dt = ds.Tables[0];

//Populate the Location Dropdown

    DataRow[] Location = dt.Select("Category = 'Location'");
    foreach (DataRow row in Location)
    {
        for (int i = 0; ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > i; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; ddlLocation.Items.Count > j; j++)
            {
                if (ddlLocation.Items[j].Value.ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString())
                {
                    ddlLocation.Items[j].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

//Populate the Department Dropdown

    DataRow[] Department = dt.Select("Category = 'Department'");
    foreach (DataRow row in Department)
    {
        for (int i = 0; ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > i; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; ddlDepartment.Items.Count > j; j++)
            {
                if (ddlDepartment.Items[j].Value.ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString())
                {
                    ddlDepartment.Items[j].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did something similar the other day and ended up making one stored procedure that had a separate SELECT statement for each dropdown on my page and assigned each dataset to its respective dropdown if you want to see. That way I only have to run the stored procedure once.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You talk about populating dropdownlists, but the only thing you do in those `foreach` loops is setting a `Selected` property. Where are those 2 Londons coming from?

Comment: It sounds like you need to remove that row from the datatable then (after you've already populate the dropdown lists), because if both dropdowns have London as an option, and that row is still in the datatable then it'll return true on the logic statement you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataView to separate your results like this way :

```
 var locationView = new DataView(dt)
 {
    RowFilter = "Category = 'Location'"
 };

foreach (DataRowView  rowView in locationView)
{
    DataRow row = rowView.Row;

    for (int j = 0; ddlLocation.Items.Count > j; j++)
    {
        if (ddlLocation.Items[j].Value.ToString() == row[0].ToString())
        {
                ddlLocation.Items[j].Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

so you can create two views one for location and another for department one time and use them whenever you need them.

I noticed that you're looping in your filtered rows then inside it looping through all your table rows. and I think this is what makes your code not functioning as you wish. I hope I helped you

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it.

Start with a stored procedure that gets the id column and the actual column that you want populating your dropdowns. You'll want a separate `SELECT` statement for each dropdown:

```
SELECT id, location
FROM LocationTable

SELECT id, department
FROM DepartmentTable
```

Then create a method for populating your dropdowns:

```
private void PopulateDropdowns()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name of your connection string"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {               
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "name of your stored procedure";

            // Double check that the connection is open                    
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();

            // Create a SqlDataAdapter and fill it with the data from your stored procedure                     
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            // Since you have so many, I would name the DataSet tables
            // These will correspond with each of your SELECT statements
            // with 0 being the first SELECT, 1 being the second SELECT and so on
            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Location";
            ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Department";

            // Then set their DataSources
            // and bind each table to its corresponding dropdown
            ddlLocation.DataSource = ds.Tables["Location"];
            ddlLocation.DataValueField = "id";
            ddlLocation.DataTextField = "location";
            ddlLocation.DataBind();

            ddlDepartment.DataSource = ds.Tables["Department"];
            ddlDepartment.DataValueField = "id";
            ddlDepartment.DataTextField = "department";
            ddlDepartment.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And if you'd like the default option in your drop down to say something other than whatever comes first from your `SELECT` statements, you can set a property called `AppendDataBoundItems` to true. Then manually add a `ListItem` to your drop down, set its `Text` to whatever you like and set its `Value` to -1 (to get it to float to the top):

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLocation" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Please Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then I put `PopulateDropdowns();` in my page load. It runs the stored procedure once and all the dropdowns on the page are populated.

Comment: the problem is my query is like 200 lines long and I dont want to write multiple table. just one

Comment: Should be fine if you have everything in one table as long as each row has a unique identifier, I just wrote my example that way for clarity. They can come from the same table but you'll still want a separate SELECT for each one